# Can the menu of emacs still be accessible in terminal?

Tags: emacs

when running Emacs inside terminal emulator, there is a menu bar on the top.

[image]
Can we select a menu item, expand it and select a sub-menu item? Under Xemacs, we can, but I haven't found a way under Emacs in terminal yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hit F10, then the first letter of each menu option.

Comment: Thanks. that works under virtual console. I am actually under gnome terminal, a terminal emulator under X. When I hit F10, it is the menu of gnome emulator will respond, not the Emacs menu.

Comment: This question is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191312/how-do-i-get-to-the-menu-in-emacs-in-console-mode.

It suggests Ctrl-F10 or Alt-`, though you can of course do M-x menu-bar-open which seems like a lot of typing to me - you could bind this to a more convenient key.